# HTML snippet from Python

Tags: python, html, cgi

I'm new to Python and CGI, so this may be trivial. But I'd like Python to produce a block of HTML whenever a visitor loads a page.

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- Beautiful website with great content -->

<!-- Suddenly... -->
<h1> Here's Some Python Output </h1>
<!-- RUN PYTHON SCRIPT, display output -->

</body>
</html>
```

Using a Python script that, for simplicity, looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html"
print 
print "<p>Hello world!</p>"
```

Most resources I was able to find demonstrate how to produce an ENTIRE webpage using a Python script. Can you invoke a Python script mid-page to produce JUST an HTML snippet?

Comment: What about people that want to run python scripts on ugly websites with trivial content?

Comment: How could you even run a python script "mod-page"?  What does that even mean?  Are you trying to write CGI as a big shell script with small pieces of Python on the shell script?  Why make it so complex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AJAX client-side, or templates server side.

A template will allow you to keep most of your page static, but use a server-side scripting language (like Python) to fill in the dynamic bits.  There are lots of good posts on Python template systems on Stackoverflow.  [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98245/what-is-your-single-favorite-python-templating-engine)

AJAX will allow you to update a page after it initially loads with results from a server.

Comment: Yeah, Python is not PHP. Embedding code in HTML is bad style and the fast road to maintenance nightmares.

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone. AJAX seems like a good place to start.
Similar example for those interested:
http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php